# laravel 5.2 - search function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I wish to make a custom search on my site.

Here is MySQL Search:

> SELECT * FROM `MyDB`.`MyTable` WHERE (`id` LIKE '%MySearch%' OR `firstname` LIKE '%MySearch%' OR `lastname` LIKE '%MySearch%' OR `email` LIKE '%MySearch%' OR `address` LIKE '%MySearch%');

How can I get that search into my Laravel Controller??

**$users = DB::table('MyTable')->where('firstname', 'MySearch')->get();**

[My Laravel Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzmcv.png)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: the answer at the bottom is correct( i was writing a full long answer but he was first,  and i just want to mention why you use $_POST? i think its better to use the Request , its more laravel way (both are correct , just an advise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for laravel 5.2:

```
$search = '%'.$_POST['name'].'%';

$users = DB::table('MyTable')
         ->where('id', 'LIKE', $search)
         ->orwhere('firstname', 'LIKE', $search)
         ->orwhere('lastname', 'LIKE', $search)
         ->orwhere('email', 'LIKE', $search)
         ->orwhere('address', 'LIKE', $search);
         ->get();
```

It work !

Answer (score 2):

```
$users = DB::table('MyTable')
         ->where('id', 'LIKE', '%MySearch%')
         ->or_where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%MySearch%')
         ->or_where('lastname', 'LIKE', '%MySearch%')
         ->or_where('email', 'LIKE', '%MySearch%')
         ->or_where('address', 'LIKE', '%MySearch%');
         ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks ! it really close to the answer!

I have made it up !

Answer (score 0):

You can build queries with 'orwhere' like bellow

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('firstname', 'like', 'John%')
                ->orWhere('lastname', 'John')
                ->get();
```

Please refer to this document before building your queries.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Answer (score 0):

This one also works for me in laravel 5.2

```
    $search = '%'.$request->search.'%';
    $result = DB::table('tours')->where('name', 'like', $search)->get();
```